# How to optimize memory usage in UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uiimageview, uiimage

I try to take screenshot of `uiwebview` and send it with observer to another UIImageView in another class.
 I using this method to take screenshot:

```
    -(UIImage*)takeScreenshoot{
    @autoreleasepool {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height));
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        [self.webPage.layer renderInContext:context];
        UIImage *__weak screenShot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        return screenShot;
    }

}
```

But then I have problem. Everytime I take screenshot with this method, memory rate grows about 10-15mb and it's not realising it. And if I take screenshot in every webviewdidfinishload, you can imagine how much it can take memory!

How can I fix that issue?

Comment: You don't need this line: CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

Comment: @Greg It's not makes lighter memory!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try calling `CGContextRelease(context);` after you have got your screen shot.

Or as @Greg said, remove the line and use `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` directly

Answer (score 1):

If possible try to use `[UIScreen snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates]` which `returns UIView` .
This is the snapshot of currently displayed content (snapshot of app).

Even apple also says " `this method is faster than trying to render the contents of the screen into a bitmap image yourself`."

According to your code, you are passing this bitmap image to just display in some other UIImageView. so i think using UIScreen method is appropriate here.

**To display UIWebView part only->**

Create another `UIView` instance. 
Set its frame to the frame of your webView.
Now add this screenShot view as subView to createdView and set its frame such that webView portion will be displayed.

Comment: You don't get it. I need this screenshot only of UiWebView.

Comment: Well, thats better, but I have tabbed browser, and if uiwebview not visible it doesnt work. :(